# How to setImageResource for multiple imageViews through getview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

This is the row of my custom listview. As you can see, there are three imageViews. How should I override the

`public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`

of my adapter class, such that, I can set imageView.setImageResource, no matter how many imageviews I have in my list. Any help is much appreciated.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px" />
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_toRightOf= "@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px" />

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_toRightOf= "@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think you also have taken Holder-Class, now you have to set resource of image of that holder class.

Comment: see this [example](http://android-example-code.blogspot.in/p/dynamic-custoized-list-view-in-android.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take on holder class inside your adapter

```
// View Holder for fast accessing List Row
private class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView image;
    public ImageView image1;
    public ImageView image2;
}
```

And getView method

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,null);
                holder.image = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
                holder.image1 = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image1);
                holder.image2 = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image2);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            // Setting Image Resource here
            holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
            holder.image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
            holder.image2.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);

            // return the listview row
            return convertView;
        }
```

In the ListView row layout `why you take LinearLayout and then RelativeLayout inside it`, Just **`take RelativeLayout as a root node.`**

Comment: Thanks; I have a list of drawables, so is there a scope of a looping mechanism in getView wherein I can iterate through the list and setImageResource for the Imageviews, even if that is at the cost of modifying my current layout?

Comment: Your list contain drawables name or id ??

Comment: `public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.call, 
        R.drawable.contacts,
        R.drawable.places, 
        R.drawable.navigation,
        R.drawable.music, 
        R.drawable.messages,
    };`

Comment: if you want to set same images in image,image1 & image2 then you can use holder.image.setImageResource(mThumblds[position]);

Comment: ok, will try that later. But I get nullpointer with this code:               `07-27 11:19:27.669: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3908): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.ImageAdapter.getView(ImageAdapter.java:73)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2093)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1802)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14518/discussion-between-android-coader-and-user1400538)